# Conflict Error when obtaining attributes in FIWARE Orion Context Broker

Tags: spring-boot, attributes, fiware, fiware-orion

I cannot get any entity attribute when I have context provider registered. I constantly get the same 409 conflict error. How can I  prevent having two objects with the same id and merge them into one?

---

### SETUP

I have whole Orion Context Broker all setup and running after following this commands:

```
docker pull mongo:3.6
docker pull fiware/orion:2.0.0
docker network create fiware_default

docker run -d --name=mongo-db --network=fiware_default \
  --expose=27017 mongo:3.6 --bind_ip_all --smallfiles
docker run -d --name fiware-orion -h orion --network=fiware_default \
  -p 1026:1026  fiware/orion:2.0.0 -dbhost mongo-db
```

---

### ENTITIES

I have one Car entity added with curl:

```
 curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '
{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001",
    "type": "Car",
    "brandName": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "Mercedes"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "geo:json",
        "value": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [0.00, 0.00]
        }
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "MyCar"
    }
}'
```

Moreover, I also registered my Context Provider:

```
 curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '
{
  "description": "Temperature",
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001",
        "type": "Car"
      }
    ],
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ]
  },
  "provider": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/api/cars/temperature/1"
    },
     "legacyForwarding": true
  }
}'
```

---

### CONTEXT PROVIDER

I exposed locally my Context Provider (exposed by my SpringBoot application written in Java 10) at http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/api/cars/temperature/1/queryContext. The JSON data (returned in html body) is in NSGI v1 format and looks like that:

```
   {
  "contextResponses": [
    {
      "contextElement": {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "temperature",
            "type": "float",
            "value": "-10"
          }
        ],
        "id": "urn:nsgi-ld:Car:001",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "type": "Car"
      },
      "statusCode": {
        "code": "200",
        "reasonPhrase": "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### PROBLEM

When I make this query:

```
curl GET 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities?type=Car&options=keyValues'
```

I receive list of objects with the same ids:

```
[{"id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001","type":"Car","brandName":"Mercedes","location":,"name":"MyCar"},{"id":"urn:nsgi-ld:Car:001","type":"Car","temperature":"-10"}]
```

1) When I try to get location attribute:

```
curl -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001/attrs/location/value'
```

I get response:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 98
Content-Type: application/json
Fiware-Correlator: 509119fa-fd27-11e8-922c-0242ac130003
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 09:29:53 GMT 

 {
        "error": "TooManyResults",
        "description": "More than one matching entity. Please refine your query"
    }
```

2) I noticed that I can remove an entity by id:

```
curl -iX DELETE 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001'
```

3) And then, I can get temperature for not existing object:

```
curl -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001/attrs/temperature/value'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain
Fiware-Correlator: 0de19b36-fd2a-11e8-8abe-0242ac130003
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 09:49:29 GMT

"-10"
```

I would like to be able to get an attribute (the location) and the attribute from the context provider (temperature) for the entity (urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001), but it looks like this entity has been somehow splitted into two entities with the same id (and the same type).

What should I do to prevent this id conflict? How to prevent having two objects with the same id when registering context provider?

Comment: In oder to have full detail please edit your question post to include the exact request you do (i.e. curl command) in the following cases: 1) "When I try to get attribute (location)" 2) "I can remove entity by id" 3) "I can get temperature for not existing object", please? Thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks @fgalan, I added exact requests in cases mentioned by you.

Comment: We have recently solved some bugs related with forwarding queries that could be related with this case. Thus, could you redeploy using `fiware/orion:latest` (instead of `:2.0.0`) and confirm if behaviour is the same or there is some change, please? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I started with `fiware/orion:latest` version, but the behavior was the same. I checked it again, but the newest version is still giving me this Conflict Error and objects with duplicated ids.

Comment: I have been testing with Orion last version and it seems to work in my case. In particular, I've executed the .test case at which I understand models your same case (please have a look and tell me if you find some differences). The CPr->CB output captured from CB logs is https://gist.github.com/fgalan/948a76a51f5bc2e8c947df79204efa97 and seems to be pretty the same the one you are using in your SpringBoot application.

Comment: Could you rung a `GET /version` operation in your Orion instance, to be sure we are using the same version? Mine is: 2.0.0-next (git version: f2a7eaf1236259646482c4eda49b33240f042ba9)

Comment: Ups, it seems the link to the .test above was not included... Here it is: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/84054543804960e4c11cb702ed746601

Comment: I do have this response from GET .../version request, so these are not the same versions:
     '{"orion": {
        "version": "2.0.0-next",
        "uptime": "0 d, 0 h, 2 m, 15 s",
        "git_hash": "a147a736a6d00acc8a7a07861923cb1f28b2f8e0",
        "compile_time": "Tue Dec 18 11:45:53 UTC 2018",
        "compiled_by": "root",
        "compiled_in": "3fe9628431b5",
        "release_date": "Tue Dec 18 11:45:53 UTC 2018",
        "doc": "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/"
    }
}'

Comment: @fgalan, is your git version available somewhere, so I could check if it is the problem? I downloaded image in the way described above in SETUP (the only difference is that I changed the `:2.0.0` tag to the `:latest`) and I got this git version.

Comment: a147a736a6d00acc8a7a07861923cb1f28b2f8e0 is fine, as it newer than mine (according to https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/commits/master, 5 commits ahead and nothing important on them, only documentation changes). Thus, I cannot explian why you and me are getting differents results of the same test case (correct in my case, incorrect in yours). Could you repeat the test ensuring that your DB are completely empty before starting the test, please?

Comment: I checked it again after ensuring that all entities, subscriptions, registrations are removed and also after restarting SpringBoot app (with post endpoint for getting this temperature context), but results are still incorrect for me.

Comment: Could you try with the script at https://gist.github.com/fgalan/84054543804960e4c11cb702ed746601 (after cleaning up databases again), pls? I mean the `--SHELL--` part, using plain `curl` instead of `orionCurl`. Just to know if following *exactly* the same steps you get a different result.

Comment: In your case I understand your SpringBoot applaction plays the role of CP1. Thus, use the port/path adapted to it in that step.

Comment: Can you explain me what is this step2 responsible for? I really do not understand why do I need to do that (and how to do that using curl) if I have my context at the registered endpoint? I do not have any Context Provider Proxy. Also data returned by my app looks differently that in this step 2 and I am not sure why is that.

Comment: In my setup I'm using a CB instance (running in a different port and using a different DB) to play the role of ContextProvider. Thus, in your case you have two options: a) skip step 2, set your app URL in step 3 and ensure it returns the expected result for a query context (e.g. pay attention to entity ID, etc.), or b) do the same I did and use a CB as Context Provider. If it works in case b) but not in case a) then probably the problem is the way your app is responding to queryContext.

Comment: Hi, @fgalan I did check this a) option, but it didn't work for me. I don't know, what can be wrong with my app responding to query Context - it returns JSON described above at the url registered as context with added `/queryContext` at the end. My app returns a temperature attrubute when `urn:ngsi-ld:Car:001` is deleted, so I assume that it works fine, right?.... I would like to test your b) approach, but I have problem with the set up. Maybe you could share your set up for two context brokers?